# how to filter in R without specify all the values

Tags: r, filter

I have a big data file in R and I want to filter one column. To simply it, it looks like this: and i want to filter only the values start with GR...but without specify the all the values bc they are many and they are changing. Could you please help me? thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EdXD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `str_detect` from `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(x1 = c("A", "B", "C", "GRTY", "GRkL", "G"))
df %>% 
        filter(str_detect(x1, pattern = "GR"))
```

Output:

```
    x1
1 GRTY
2 GRkL
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grepl` you could do:

```r
dd <- data.frame(
  x1 = c("A", "B", "C", "GRTY", "GRkL", "G")
)
dd[grepl("^GR", dd$x1),, drop = FALSE]
#>     x1
#> 4 GRTY
#> 5 GRkL
```